# mod_rewrite: redirect url on second layer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

want to redirect all request from a syntax like

http://www.example.com/goto/xxxxxx

to

http://www.example.com/articles/xxxxxx

(xxxxxx) is the variable that needs be submitted.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /goto/(.*)$ /articles/$1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost correct but leading slash is the problem in your rule. `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

If you want to redirect then following rule will work in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ /articles/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

In case you don't want URL to change in browser then use:

```
RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ /articles/$1 [L,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule goto/(.*)$ articles/$1
```